# Dynamically change hostname in Bash PS1 prompt

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

I have a bash prompt that includes my hostname using either the `\h` variable (interpreted by `PS1`) or `$(uname -n)`. Whichever one I use doesn't seem to make a difference.

For software licensing reasons, I sometimes have to change my hostname, which is done by calling a script that updates files `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`, and also calls `$ hostname NEWNAME` for good measure.

When the script updates my hostname, I would like the shell which invoked the script to have its `PS1` prompt reflect the change -- to show the new hostname. The only way I know to do this is by resourcing my `.bashrc` which defines `PS1`. But calling `. "${HOME}/.bashrc"` within the script is only going to modify that script's environment and not the caller's, as I understand it.

So how can I get the caller's `PS1` prompt updated as well to show the new hostname automatically?

Comment: Are you saying that `\h` doesn't change dynamically based on the hostname?

Comment: Changing all of those should set it properly, but you could always make `PS1` a function.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams correct, not until I launch a new shell (or manually resource `.bashrc`) does `\h` show the current hostname (GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release)

Comment: You can change the value of `PS1` anytime you want; the only thing special about `.bashrc` is that is contains commands that are executed when an interactive shell first starts. Type `PS1="this is my new prompt "` at any prompt (assuming you aren't using `PROMPT_COMMAND`) to see the result.

Comment: You can change it any time you want, but not from an external process. That's intentionally impossible: The shell needs to cooperate to update its internal state.

Comment: That said, it sounds like you're setting your PS1 using `"$(uname -n)"` (so it's evaluated only once), instead of `'$(uname -n)'` (evaluated every time the prompt is printed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if that were the case, I wouldn't see the correct hostname when I start a new shell or resource my `.bashrc`. I think you might be misunderstanding the problem

Comment: @ardnew, that's completely consistent with the behavior described -- sourcing your `.bashrc` would rerun the expansion.

Comment: @ardnew, if you want to prove or disprove that theory, run `declare -p PS1` and provide its value. If it contains a literal string `$(uname -n)` rather than the hostname itself, then I'm wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using `\h` anyway, I'm not using an `$(...)` expansion

Comment: If you switch to the `$(...)` expansion **with single quotes**, does it solve your problem? If so, while we wouldn't want to stick with that as a long-term solution, it gives us a substantial clue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but to your point, I've replaced `\h` with `PS1="otherstuff"'$(uname -n)'"morestuff"` and it's working great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156225/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-ardnew).

Comment: BTW, can you edit the title here to look less like a request for something that's (as aforementioned) impossible? While my answer addresses your problem to your satisfaction, it's unlikely to be helpful to someone else who comes here wanting to know how to "have [a] bash script update [its] caller's PS1".

Comment: That might be as simple as making it "Hostname in bash PS1 not being updated".

Comment: @tadman, are you sure you aren't thinking of zsh functionality, or otherwise a non-bash shell? In bash, the accepted way to dynamically update PS1 is to set the variable from code referenced in `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's exactly what I'm talking about: `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Make a function if you want it to evaluate each time.

Comment: @tadman, ahh. I assumed when you said "make PS1 a function", you actually meant that literally (a function named PS1).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You clarified it better than I did, that's for sure. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is the key here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- With `\h`

  Bash uses the internal variable `current_host_name`. To quote the code which sets it, **run only once at startup time**:

  ```c
  /* It's highly unlikely that this will change. */
  if (current_host_name == 0)
    {
      /* Initialize current_host_name. */
      if (gethostname (hostname, 255) < 0)
        current_host_name = "??host??";
      else
        current_host_name = savestring (hostname);
    }
  ```

  While the shell also initializes the shell variable `HOSTNAME` to this same value, it's not a two-way relationship: You can't update `current_host_name` by modifying `HOSTNAME`. Fixing this would require patching the shell.
- With `$(uname -n)`

  This is dynamically updated **only if you use single quotes when assigning it to `PS1`**. That is:

  ```
  # Check uname every time the prompt is rendered
  PS1='....$(uname -n)...'
  ```

  *not*

  ```
  # Check uname only once, at shell startup
  PS1="....$(uname -n)..."
  ```

Comment: Doesn't this run a `uname` process for each shell prompt instance?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's awful and inefficient, to be sure; if I were doing this for myself, I'd *at least* move the logic into a `PROMPT_COMMAND` function and only run `uname` a maximum of every so many seconds.